# functions with ControllerAs pattern are called multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I follow the "controller as" usage from [angularjs styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#controlleras-view-syntax) to create a controller, which has a function in it to be called from view (such as `ng-if`). However when I called the function, it seems it was called three times, but I have no idea how it happened.
Here is the JSBin [link](http://jsbin.com/wunowelefe/3/edit)

```js
(function() {
  angular.module('app', []);

  function test() {
    console.log('init');
    var vm = this;
    vm.title = "test title";
    vm.called = function() {
      console.log('get called');
    }
  }

  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('test', test);

})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="test as vm">
    {{ vm.title }} {{ vm.called(); }}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have control over how many times the expressions used in `{{binding}}`s are evaluated. AngularJS re-evaluates them every time it thinks their values might have changed. In other words, if an expression contains a function call, it is called on every `$digest`.

This means that you should be *very* concerned about performance impact when using function calls in AngularJS expressions. Usually it's possible (and much better) to bind to a scope variable. If you had this in a large application, where `$rootScope.$digest` was called more often, you'd see many more calls to that same function.